# Applying a function of type String -> [String] -> [String] to two [String]s

Tags: string, list, function, haskell, types

I struggled to come up with a good title for this.

Here's the gist:

I have a function (`remIgnored`) that intends to remove strings from a list of strings.

```
module Main(main) where

import System.Environment
import Data.List
import Data.Char

getLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getLines path = do 
    ls <- readFile path
    return (lines ls)

getWords :: [String] -> [String]
getWords ws = words (unlines ws)

remIgnored :: String -> [String] -> [String]
remIgnored _ []                 = []
remIgnored x (y:ys) | x == y    = remIgnored x ys
                    | otherwise = y : remIgnored x ys

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let path = args !! 0
    let ignore = args !! 1
    ig <- getLines ignore
    ls <- getLines path
    let ig'  = map (map toLower) (getWords ig)
    let ls'  = map (map toLower) (getWords ls)
    let ls'' = sort ls'
    putStrLn "Original Lines:\n"
    mapM_ putStrLn ls
    putStrLn "\nLower Cased Words:\n"
    mapM_ putStrLn ls'
    putStrLn "\nLower Cased Words + Sorted:\n"
    mapM_ putStrLn ls''
    putStrLn "\nLower Cased Words + Sorted + Sanitized:\n"
    --Something nice goes here
```

(Please ignore the constant duplicating with minor changes to the lists, I am just hacking things about to see how they work).

Basically, my question is this: How would I go about applying the function `remIgnored` to the list `ls''` with every element in `ig'`? I've been staring at type errors all night and I am making little progress (even what I have so far has caused me a great deal of annoyance).

For reference, my input files:

`test.txt`:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Peter picked a pail of pickled peppers
She sells sea shells by the sea shore
```

`ignore.txt`:

```
a
the
of
by
```

Sample Output:

```
Original Lines:
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy
Peter picked a pail of pickled peppers
She sells sea shells by the sea shore

Lower Cased Words:
the
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog
peter
picked
a
pail
of
pickled
peppers
she
sells
sea
shells
by
the
sea
shore

Lower Cased Words + Sorted:
a
brown
by
dog
fox
jumps
lazy
of
over
pail
peppers
peter
picked
pickled
quick
sea
sea
sells
she
shells
shore
the
the
the

Lower Cased Words + Sorted + Sanitized:
```

Comment: @Zeta, the code, as it stands, compiles. My various attempts to smash `remIgnored` together with `ig` `ls''` have caused me some hilarious problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In reality, you should use a fold to do that.

```hs
remAllIgnored :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
remAllIgnored = flip $ foldr remIgnored
```

yup, it's really that simple.

If you're not comfortable with folds yet, you can code this explicitly with recursion of the ignore-list:

```
remAllIgnored [] words = ... -- nothing to ignore means: ?
remAllIgnored (ign0:igns) words
    = let ??  -- somehow you need to 1. apply the `ign0`-ignore-patch
      in ??   --                     2. process the rest of the `igns`
```

Try it, and if there are any particular problems come back with those.

Comment: I don't really understand either of those. How does `remAllIgnored` actually _do_ anything? (In that first case, with `foldr`)

Comment: It worked, but would you mind explaining what actually like, _happened_? Everything in Haskell seems like black magic to me at this stage.

Comment: Well, to understand the fold you should implement the recursive version, which is after all equivalent. And you'll really have to do that _yourself_ I'm afraid, to understand it properly. At least try – where do you get stuck? Step `[]`, step `1.` or step `2.`?

Comment: @capncoolio Perhaps the `foldr` version is more understandable in a pointful style, i.e. `remAllIgnored toIgnore words = foldr remIgnored words toIgnore`. This roughly expands to `(remIgnored toIgn1 (... (remIgnored toIgnN words)))` where all the ignored words are removed from the `words` list one by one.

Comment: @capncoolio Have you used `foldr` before? This diagram, I feel, gives a good visual explanation of how it works. `foldr` turns the list its given (on the left of the image) into the nested function call on the right: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Right-fold-transformation.png. It "replaces" the list's  `:`s with `f` calls and the empty list with `z`. The list on the left is the long way of writing `[1,2,3,4,5]`. It would help to write out a small example by hand.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I'm currently stuck trying to understand how I would go about implementing the recursive version. You've got `remAllIgnored (ign0:igns) words = let ??` there. Isn't `words` a function? Also, isn't `let`  generally used in the context of the `IO` monad?

Comment: Your're right, `words` is already a standard function, I shouldn't have used that name. (Mind, it'll still work: the local definition of the argument `words` simply shadows the global value `Prelude.words`.) As for `let`, there are two different syntaxes, one in a monadic context (without `in`), one [in general functional expressions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where). You don't need `let ... in ...` to implement that function, it's just what I would have written.